# Where should I put my script?

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems

Say I have created a bash script, which will make an ftp user, mount some paths for that user, etc. Where in the file system it would be proper to place? It would be good to have some resource clearly explaining the file system hierarchy.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

A Google search for "Linux file system hierarchy" will turn up several documents, including [this one](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/).

Where you put your script depends on who the intended user is. If it is just you, put it in `~/bin` and make sure `~/bin` is in your `PATH`. If any user on the system should be able to run the script, put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

**Don't** put scripts you write yourself in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`. Those directories are intended for programs managed by the operating system.

Comment: Here is a [direct link](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) to the home of the documentation.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu and found that `~/bin` will be automatically included in your `$PATH` once the folder is created.  There are lines in `.profile`:  `if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi`

Comment: Thanks!  For others as inexperienced as me:  (1) you either need to log out and back in after creating ~/bin , or run `source ~/.profile` before ~/bin  gets added to your PATH  (2) you also have to run `chmod u+x ~/bin/<your script>` to give yourself privilege to execute it.